# How to draw lines in .ply files using Meshlab?

Tags: 3d, mesh, 3d-reconstruction, meshlab, ply-file-format

For example, I want to choose two points from all the point clouds, and draw a line between them. I'm using Meshlab to deal with .ply files but I don't know how to accomplish this. Can I do this using Meshlab or other ways?

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to add lines to .ply files. The most habitual elements found in .ply files are `vertex` and `face`, but the [.ply file format](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/) also allows the definition of segments using the `edge` which are **only partially** supported by Meshlab.

This is a minimal example of a .ply file with two vertex and one edge element

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
comment object: A single line
element vertex 2
property float x
property float y
property float z
element edge 1                        
property int vertex1                  
property int vertex2                  
end_header
0 0 0 
0 0 1 
0 1
```

And this is a more complex example, with color per vertex and 4 lines in the corners of a cube.

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
comment object: 4 edges with color per vertex
element vertex 8
property float x
property float y
property float z
property uchar red                   
property uchar green
property uchar blue
element edge 4
property int vertex1                  
property int vertex2                  
end_header

0 0 0 255 0 0 
0 0 1 255 0 0
0 1 1 255 0 0
0 1 0 255 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 255
1 0 1 0 0 255
1 1 1 0 0 255
1 1 0 0 0 255

0 4 
1 5 
2 6 
3 7
```

This is how previous example is rastered by meshlab

[image: Output of sample 2]

As I said, meshlab supports `edge` element just partially, so it has some problems:

- Meshlab will load .ply files with edge elements, but will not save then to ply file format. It will only export vertex and faces to file.
- Meshlab has problems representing files with both `edge` and `face` elements. It will only correctly plot them if edges are in a separate layer from faces (as show in image below). So, if you need to plot a .ply file with both faces and lines, you will have to:

  1. Duplicate the current layer.
  2. Select all faces from new layer and remove them (Del key), so the `edge` elements come visible on that layer. The `face` elements are still visible in the original layer.

[image: Edges and faces are show only in separate layers]

Comment: I copied your codes into a .txt files and dragged in MeshLab editor and I don't see any points / cube, any ideas why?

Comment: Try to use the .ply extension instead of .txt

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in draw some temporary segments on any mesh, you can just use the `Measuring Tool` to plot some lines. Keep in mind that those lines will be lost if you exit the measuring tool.

[image]